Setting cookie from java spring boot rest API to angular. Changing port
I have a small Rest API built with Spring Boot and an angular (18) front end. What I want is to get a cookie from the back end sent to the front end. When I do another call from the front end to the back end I want that cookie to be send to the back end.
The back end is running on port 8080 and de front end on port 4200. I have looked thru a lot of answers here on stackoverflow and tried to follow numerous tutorials and blogs.
The cookie is used to identify a client. I do not want a session cookie or a cookie to secure my service, that is a task for the future.
My rest api has @RestController, @RequestMapping("/api") and @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*", methods = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE }) annotations.
First I call en endpoint called getnewid.
    @GetMapping("/getnewid")
    public String getNewID(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @CookieValue(value = Util.CLIENT_ID_COOKIE_NAME, defaultValue = "") String cookieValue)
            throws CabinException {

        Cookie cookie = Util.getNewID(request.getRemoteAddr(), request.getHeader("User-Agent"), cookieValue);

        response.addCookie(cookie);
        response.setStatus(200);

        return cookie.getValue();

    }

That calls a Util class to generate a new cookie.
        String tmpCookieClientID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Cookie clientIDCookie = new Cookie("cabinCTRLclientID", tmpCookieClientID);
        clientIDCookie.setDomain("localhost");
        clientIDCookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
        return clientIDCookie;


If I call the endpoint directly in Firefox I get the cookie with the "correct" host.

If I call the endpoint from my Angular app, I the the "wrong" host.

The following is from the angular service and the code that calls the service
  getNewKey(): Observable<string> {
    return this.httpClient.get<string>(this.baseURL + "getnewid");
  }


  getNewKey() {
    this.subs.add(this.clientService.getNewKey().subscribe(key => console.log(key))
    );
  }

Any help is greatly appreciated.

what do you mean by "host"?  Localhosts with different ports are treated as separate domains by CORS rules, but cookies are agnostic to the port.  The front end will show it's own port, but it's not relevant for cookies.

You'll need to use the proxy provided by the cli to redirect traffic from 4200 to 8080

@browsermator Not sure what "agnostic" means, but if I do not add the CrossOrigin annotation to the controller none of the calls from the front end is accepted by the back end and I get an CORS error in the console log in the web browser.

@RobinDijkhof I tried to use the proxy functionality that angular supplies. Did not work.
